# Simplify sql query logic

Tags: sql

I have the following query that is used in a stored procedure.  I am trying to simplify the logic in the CASE statement.  Specifically I would like to nest the Product inside the UserGroup.

```
SELECT DCMNumber, 
       SUM(CONVERT(INT, CurrentlyAssigned)) AS PriorAssigned
FROM dbo.cauAssignedClaim WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE RecordType = 'A' 
  AND ([Status] <> 'DE' OR [Status] IS NULL)
  AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, EntryDate)) 
      BETWEEN 
          CASE 
             WHEN Product IN('LTD', 'LTDCP') AND @UserGroup = '' OR @UserGroup = 'NONE'     
                 THEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-30)) 
             WHEN Product IN('STD', 'STDCP', 'SALCN', 'STAT', 'OFFOV') AND @UserGroup = '' OR @UserGroup = 'NONE' 
                 THEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-14)) 
             WHEN Product IN('LTD', 'LTDCP') AND @UserGroup IN('SSAT', 'TCMS') 
                 THEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-7)) 
             WHEN Product IN('STD', 'STDCP', 'SALCN', 'STAT', 'OFFOV') AND @UserGroup IN('Appeals', 'DMS', 'Life', 'WOP', 'IWOP') 
                 THEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-7)) 
          END 
      AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-1)) 
GROUP BY [Status], DCMNumber
```

Comment: What is this expression about? `([Status] <> 'DE' OR [Status] IS NULL AND [Status] IS NULL)`

Comment: The "@" values in the case/when are values that are passed into the stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This from your original:

```
BETWEEN 
      CASE 
         WHEN Product IN('LTD', 'LTDCP') AND @UserGroup = '' OR @UserGroup = 'NONE'     
             THEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-30)) 
         WHEN Product IN('STD', 'STDCP', 'SALCN', 'STAT', 'OFFOV') AND @UserGroup = '' OR @UserGroup = 'NONE' 
             THEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-14)) 
         WHEN Product IN('LTD', 'LTDCP') AND @UserGroup IN('SSAT', 'TCMS') 
             THEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-7)) 
         WHEN Product IN('STD', 'STDCP', 'SALCN', 'STAT', 'OFFOV') AND @UserGroup IN('Appeals', 'DMS', 'Life', 'WOP', 'IWOP') 
             THEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-7)) 
      END 
  AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-1))
```

Can factor out the date functions like this:

```
BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE() - 
      CASE 
         WHEN Product IN('LTD', 'LTDCP') AND @UserGroup IN ('', 'NONE') THEN 30
         WHEN Product IN('STD', 'STDCP', 'SALCN', 'STAT', 'OFFOV') AND @UserGroup IN ('', 'NONE') THEN 14
         WHEN (Product IN('LTD', 'LTDCP') AND @UserGroup IN ('SSAT', 'TCMS')) 
           OR (Product IN('STD', 'STDCP', 'SALCN', 'STAT', 'OFFOV') AND @UserGroup IN('Appeals', 'DMS', 'Life', 'WOP', 'IWOP'))
           THEN 7
      END ))
  AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-1))
```

Depending on the possible values for your `Product` column, you may also be able to do something like:

```
  CASE WHEN Product LIKE 'LTD%' ...
       WHEN Product LIKE 'STD%' ...
```

Finally, you are missing a default case. You can remove one of those conditions entirely by replacing it with an `ELSE` clause, and I would highly recommend doing so. I suspect the most accurate default would be 30, but the greatest simplification can be had by defaulting to 7:

```
BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE() - 
      CASE 
         WHEN Product LIKE 'LTD%' AND @UserGroup IN ('', 'NONE') THEN 30
         WHEN Product IN ('STD', 'STDCP', 'SALCN', 'STAT', 'OFFOV') AND @UserGroup IN ('','NONE') THEN 14
         ELSE 7
      END ))
  AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-1))
```

Comment: Thanks Joel! I really appreciate your solution.